# Spring JPA H2 and DB2 How to specify table schema to work on both databases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2, h2, database-schema

I am creating a Springboot app which I am planning to talk to DB2 database for production and to H2 database for development environments which I have setup using spring application.profiles.

My application.properties file also has setting:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

, which if set, will not replace "." with "_" (as in `MY_SCHEMA.CAR` with `MY_SCHEMA_CAR`).

I need this since on DB2, I have to prefix table with schema like `SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.CAR`.  In H2 console, this is not needed and I can just do `SELECT * FROM CAR`.

However, I am running into following problem:

1. if my entity is annotated with `@Table(name = "MY_SCHEMA.CAR")` , I get DB2 error
   **error com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
   SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=MY_USER;CREATE TABLE FOR USER
   MY_SCHEMA;MY_SCHEMA.CAR, DRIVER=4.29.24**.  On H2, this creates table MY_SCHEMA.CAR.
2. if my entity is annotated with `@Table(name = "CAR", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")`, it works with DB2 but on H2, I get error
   **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "MY_SCHEMA" not
   found; SQL statement: create table MY_SCHEMA.CAR (...**

How do I address issue in #2 above to get it working on my H2 database as well?

Comment: "...I need this since on DB2, I have to prefix table with schema..." -- No, you don't have to. Just append `:currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA;` to the JDBC URL when connecting (and don't forget the ending semicolon). This extra connection parameter sets the default schema, so you don't need to hardcode it in your SpringBoot app.

Comment: @TheImpaler Are you saying I need to set my datasource url like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://my_server:PORT/MY_DB:currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA;` ?  Thank you

Comment: Yep, looks good to me. As an example on my sandbox, I connect using `jdbc:db2://192.168.56.218:50000/empusa:currentSchema=ECOS;`.

Comment: Thank you, that works, the only problem now I have is I cannot connect to my h2 console.  Can you provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I prefer not to hardcode the default schema in the app. If the schema changes for any reason the app doesn't need to be affected.

To do that, remove the schema on the SpringBoot app. You'll need to change the JDBC connection URL, though. Append `:currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA;` to set the default schema.

For example, when connecting to DB2 in my sandbox I use:

```
jdbc:db2://192.168.56.218:50000/empusa:currentSchema=ECOS;
```

H2 offers a similar feature. When I connect to my H2 database I use:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;SCHEMA=ECOS
```

Comment: It works for DB2 but maven > install for H2 fails with **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "MY_SCHEMA" not found; SQL statement:
SET SCHEMA DB2TST6 [90079-200]** error and **Schema "MY_SCHEMA" not found; SQL statement:
SET SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA[90079-200]** after setting datasource url like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:MY_DB;SCHEMA=MY_SCHEMA`

Comment: Thank you. I will mark your answer because it helped me with DB2 but I am having still issue with H2 connectivity if I add `:SCHEMA=MY_SCHEMA` to the datasource.url as explained in above comment.

Comment: @pixel The H2 setting works for me. I don't know where I got it from, though, since I'm looking at the H2 page (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes) and I can't find it now. I would try it out using a simple JDBC client first, like Squirrel SQL client, to verify it works.

Comment: I will take a look, thank you but it is not working for me.  What is the annotation of your Entity?  Mine has `@Entity` and `@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")`